# Eliyahu Hanavi drinking from cup

Tags: sources-mekorot, passover, eliyahu-hanavi

Is there a source to the fact that Eliyahu Hanavi drinks from the Kos Shel Eliyahu when he comes on the Seder night?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works? Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Perhaps not quite a duplicate since you seem to be specifically asking about whether he drinks, but we have several questions asking for sources that he comes to begin with: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/90629/sources-about-door-opening-at-the-seder https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/90887/is-eliyahu-hanuvy-real https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30284/elijah-at-passover-seder

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR the source that Eliyahu "drinks" from each cup at the seder can be (at most) traced back a few hundred years**

An OU.org article titled "[Eliyahu HaNavi at the Seder](https://www.ou.org/torah/machshava/tzarich-iyun/eliyahu-hanavi-seder/)" adresses this topic.

### But

Before we determine whether Eliyahu Hanavi drinks from every kiddush cup designated  for him at the seder, does he even even **APPEAR** at the seder?

The article states:

> **There is no classical (Talmudic or midrashic) source stating that Eliyahu pays a visit to the Seder every year.**
>
> **A common custom is to take a large decorative cup, fill it with wine**, and leave it on the Seder table for a part of, or according to some, for the entire, Seder (see [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 119:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.119.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). **[This] is known as the Kos shel Eliyahu**, Eliyahu’s Cup. **This custom is not found in the Talmud, the Rishonim, the Tur, or the Shulchan Aruch**.

However, in terms of Eliyahu drinking from the cup:

> **The lack of a source did not prevent many**, in particular Chassidim, **from popularizing the idea that Eliyahu** makes a furtive appearance, **even drinks from the cup**, and disappears again.

Most notably:

> Perhaps the most extreme proponent of this idea was **[Rabbi Sholom Dov Ber Schneersohn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sholom_Dovber_Schneersohn)**, the fifth Lubavitcher Rebbe (1860-920) who, **before pouring wine from Eliyahu’s Cup back into the wine bottle, would add additional wine because he was concerned that the wine in the cup was pagum** (**i.e., the cup had been drunk from**, rendering the wine unusable for other mitzvot unless additional wine is added) (Rabbi Yehoshua Mundshine, Otzar Minhagei Chabad 175:3[5755], 202).