Is Kos shel Eliyahu pogum?
Is the Kos shel Eliyahu after he drinks from it considered Pogum, and there fore one would not be allowed to use it until it is rectified?

He would have to drink from it for there to be a question to begin with. At the end of the Seder seeing the cup is untouched I follow the ming's to sing keli atoh while pouring the wine/grape juice back into the bottle

@Dude the tradition is, that he drinks from it. The Minhag of pouring his cup back in to a bottle whilst singing keli ato is Minhag Chabad. But for example if one doesn't have enough wine and needs to use it for his fourth Kos, is the wine pogum?

That's not a tradition, it's a lie people tell their kids to get them excited.

@magicker72 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103181/eliyahu-hanavi-drinking-from-cup/103184#103184

Your question is answered there too. The Rashab made a point of "fixing" the wine, but apparently it was a novel practice.

@shmosel the Rebbe rashab is a good
source for me!

I attended the second Seder with Rav Yisroel Reisman. He used grape juice for Kos shel Eliyahu. He personally poured it directly back into the bottle at the end of the seder without regards to pogum.

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!
